# Keras LSTM Batch Size and model.fit()

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am training an LSTM in Keras. As per documentation, my training data and labels have shape (20, 20, 1) representing 20 samples with 20 time steps and one feature. When I use `model.fit()` to train my model, do I need to specify `batch size` or will all 20 samples be sent as one batch by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Keras's `fit` [documentation](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/fit.html)

> **batch_size** Integer or NULL. Number of samples per gradient update. If unspecified, batch_size will **default to 32**.

Comment: So does that mean it will loop through all data points 32 times and see 20*32 samples per batch?

Comment: `batch size` is the number of samples loaded per forward/backward pass.
That means each **epoch** the whole dataset (20 samples) will pass through the NN.

Comment: Ok and since `batch size` is greater than the number of samples, will only one batch per epoch be sent through?

Comment: correct. Each epoch will have only one batch of 20 samples.

Comment: Thanks for your help